# Oracle NUMBER to TIME

Tags: oracle, plsql

Im writing some ETL to get data out of a legacy Oracle db and into SQL Server db for Analysis services etc.

The legacy oracle database is storing several time columns as Number(4,2).

```
9 = 09:00
1.2 = 01:20
11.53 = 11:53
```

Are there any built in functions that will convert this to a Time data type?  Has anyone come across this before?  How did you solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think `NUMERIC` would store `11:53`.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `TIME` datatype - it has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` both of which have a date and a time component.

Comment: Oracle does have TIME data type but it's undocumented and unsupported - SELECT TIME'12:34:56' FROM DUAL - works but it doesn't make sense to use it. See http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2012/12/29/a-tip-for-lazy-oracle-users-type-less-with-ansi-date-and-timestamp-sql-syntax/ for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not have a `TIME` datatype - it has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` both of which have a date and a time component.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b09cf/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE times ( time ) AS
          SELECT  9    FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  1.2  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 15.53 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 24.62 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - Get the correct time component for numbers which are valid times**:

```
SELECT time,
       TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( time, '00.00' ), 'HH24.MI' ) AS parsed_time
FROM   times
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( TO_CHAR( time, '00.00' ), '([01]\d|2[0-3]).[0-5]\d' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b09cf/3/0)**:

```
|  TIME |                 PARSED_TIME |
|-------|-----------------------------|
|     9 | September, 01 2015 09:00:00 |
|   1.2 | September, 01 2015 01:20:00 |
| 15.53 | September, 01 2015 15:53:00 |
```

**Query 2 - Get the correct time component for numbers which are valid times with today's date**:

```
SELECT time,
       TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) || ' ' || TO_CHAR( time, '00.00' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI' ) AS parsed_time
FROM   times
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( TO_CHAR( time, '00.00' ), '([01]\d|2[0-3]).[0-5]\d' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b09cf/3/1)**:

```
|  TIME |                 PARSED_TIME |
|-------|-----------------------------|
|     9 | September, 28 2015 09:00:00 |
|   1.2 | September, 28 2015 01:20:00 |
| 15.53 | September, 28 2015 15:53:00 |
```

**Query 3 - Get the correct time component for any number of hours (unit part) and minutes (decimal part)**:

```
SELECT time,
       TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + TRUNC(time)/24 + (time - TRUNC(time)) * 100 / 60/ 24 AS parsed_time
FROM   times
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b09cf/3/2)**:

```
|  TIME |                 PARSED_TIME |
|-------|-----------------------------|
|     9 | September, 28 2015 09:00:00 |
|   1.2 | September, 28 2015 01:20:00 |
| 15.53 | September, 28 2015 15:53:00 |
| 24.62 | September, 29 2015 01:02:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: Corrected the query as per MT0. This will also take care of scenario when you have `:` in between instead of `.`

```
        with tbl as(
        select 9 as tf from dual union all
        select 1.2 from dual union all
        select 11.53 as tf from dual 
        )
        select TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( replace(to_char(tf),':','.'), '00.00' ), 'HH24.MI' ) AS time from tbl
```

EDIT1: It will only work for the values you gave. If you have something which is not a valid time, then it will fail saying

```
 ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
 or
 ORA-01851: minutes must be between 0 and 59
```

Comment: For `1.2` it will return `01:02` rather than `01:20`.

Comment: Yeah I see it now. Good catch. Your query seems to overcome this. Thanks.

Comment: @MT0 Corrected it. This will also take care of `:` in between. Thanks for your query.

Comment: I don't see how you could have a ":" in there.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Maybe OP made a typo, but if it is there by mistake, the replace part will take care of it.